# Elegant way to add an array on each column dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a 1D array on each column of a pandas dataframe.

Exemple :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
s = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 1))
```

Is there a way more elegant way than :

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col] + s
```

Obviously, summ = df + s doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I had to specify axis=0 in my answer. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy level to do that :

```
df.iloc[:] = df.values+ s
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
s = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 1))

df

    A   B   C   D
0  44  47  64  67
1  67   9  83  21
2  36  87  70  88
3  88  12  58  65

s

array([[39],
       [87],
       [46],
       [88]])
```

---

Use `df.add`. You'll need to unravel `s`, because of its dimension.

```
df.add(s.ravel(), axis=0)

     A    B    C    D
0   83   86  103  106
1  154   96  170  108
2   82  133  116  134
3  176  100  146  153
```

Comment: bad axis ? Op want to sum columns.

Comment: @B.M. Thanks, you helped me realise the axis was wrong. Returned the favour with an upvote.